# Normalizer of the group of segment $C^\infty$ diffeomorphisms in the group of segment homeomorphisms

Tags: gr.group-theory, differential-topology

What is the normalizer of the group of $C^\infty$ diffeomorphisms on $[0, 1]$, with group law given by composition, in the group of all homeomorphisms of $[0, 1]$?

If the answer is known, is there some "elementary" proof for the result?

Comment: What is the (not commutative) group structure of $C^0[0,1]$?

Comment: It refers to only the homeprphisms and smooth diffeomorphisms, respectively, with composition as the group multiplication.

Comment: You should make your question much more explicit. Otherwise it will be closed, I think.

Comment: The question is interesting. Maybe you could change the notaion (and title), because usually $C^0[0,1]$ refers to the continuous, real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ and not to the homeomorphisms of $[0,1]$ and similar for $C^\infty$.

Comment: Tranks a lot for changing title and text. It is perfectly precise now.

Comment: I guess it comes from the question of determining the automorphism group of $\mathrm{Diff}^\infty([0,1])$ as Rubin spatiality theorems might reduce to determining this normalizer. I guess it's not trivial and one shouldn't expect a too easy answer.

Comment: Filipkiewicz proved in "Isomorphisms between diffeomorphism
groups", 1982, that every isomorphism (as abstract groups) between $Diff^k(M)$ and $Diff^k(N)$ is induced by a $C^k$-diffeo between $M$ and $N$, if $1 \leq k \leq \infty$ and $M, N$ are paracompact manifolds *without* boundary. So, I think, the problem reduces to finding normaliser of $Diff([0, 1])$ inside $Diff((0, 1))$, which should be known.